# Migration from ink! 3.3.1 to upcoming 4.0

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Will it be possible to upgrade from ink! 3.3.1 to ink 4.0 on-chain via set_code_hash while keeping the contract storage?

A lot of questions are rising from ink! 4.0 so any other clarification is welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The way ink! 4.0 does storage was completely reworked. In general, you cannot expect to be able to re-use the storage during such an upgrade.